# how to change font for <select>

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to get font from google for one of my project.

Font is working perfectly, but for `<select>` font is not coming.

Any idea how to apply font for select, option in jsf?

I tried in style, by making class etc... but nothing is working.

[image]

Below is what I have in source code even when I have select {font-family: 'fontName'}

```
<select name="j_idt205" size="1">
    <option value="Any" selected="selected">Any</option>
    <option value="Muslim">Muslim</option>
    <option value="Christian">Christian</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
```

---

### Main Problem

**In FF, its proper, but in Chrome, its default Chrome font.**

Any idea why this is happening?

Upon further investigation, I found this is happening with MAC Chrome and Safari only. **This is just driving me crazy!!!**

Comment: Before you rant off on JSF, please realize that this is a plain HTML problem, not a JSF problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when taking JSF-generated HTML output into a standalone `.html` file. In order to generate better attention and answers, I recommend to leave out the irrelevant JSF noise in this kind of HTML/CSS specific questions.

Comment: @BalusC : removed the tag of jsf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement font-family on select

http://jsfiddle.net/sTPFY/

```
 select {font-family:fontname}
```

Comment: in jsfiddle ? if yes than you are checking in which browser?

Comment: ahh its a problem with Chrome :(

Comment: im win 8 and mac safari and chrome attitude is same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34288/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-hushme)

Comment: @Hushme you are right because i tried your suggestion and it's working for me . :)